# Android: Passing String Array over Multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, arrays, bundle

I am trying to pass a single string array through about 3 classes to finally have the contents of the array[1] printed to a textview. I've been using intent to achieve this with my arraylists and it works fine. For some reason I'm unable to get it working with a measly string array. Here's what I'm doing.

Origin Activity of String Array:

```
private String [] decisionInput = new String[1];

 textData = etShouldI.getText().toString();

            if (!textData.matches("")){

            decisionInput[0] = (String.valueOf(textData));

                test.setText(decisionInput[0]); //TEST WORKS

               //CREATE BUNDLE
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArray("decision", decisionInput);

                //SEND BUNDLE DATA
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Pro.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);}
```

In my next Activity I've got the following, in order to receive the data, and send it off to the next Activity, and so on...

```
  String[] dPasser = new String[1];

@ONCREATE

//BUNDLE RECEIVER
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    dPasser = bundle.getStringArray("decision");


    thisText.setText(String.valueOf(dPasser));  //TV currently returns null... 

@ONCLICK

//SEND DECISION DATA TO NEXT ACTIVITY
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Next.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putStringArray("decision", dPasser);
            intent.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(intent);
```

What the $%@& am I doing wrong guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the code below in a file named data, in your code you then use just it by calling `data.array`

```
public class data {
     public String[] array = new String[1];
}
```

But going with just passing through a String[] you shouldn't need bundle.

simply

```
intent.putExtra("stringArray".String[]);
```

and get it with

```
this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("stringArray")
```

Comment: Could you give me a quick example of how to use
    public class data {
public String[] array;
}

I'm not quite sure how I'd implement that.

Comment: Because my array receives data from an EditText, I'm not quite sure how to append data to the classed String array, sorry for the noobery.

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't notice that you wanted a one on it. Redid.

Comment: creating the class works, but appending data doesn't for me. I'll just have to use the other method you supplied. Thanks for the help!